# mongoose: why I'm not getting error response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I wrote this route to find user every time I'm entering wrong user I didn't getting res.json() msg

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){

    user.findOne({email : req.body.username}, function(err, user){
          if(err){
            res.json('user not found');  //not getting this 
          }else{  
            console.log(user);  //probably this ran, cuz getting null at cmd
          }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When username doesn't match with any of document  , it returns empty user json . Error err object is null so res.json is unreachable , so you have to handle this by

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){

        user.findOne({email : req.body.username}, function(err, user){
              if(err){
                throw err;
              }else{ 
                if(user){
                  console.log(user);  //probably this ran, cuz getting null at cmd
                }else{
                  console.log("User Not Found");
                }

              }
        })
    })
```

Comment: then why there is err parameter in callback, if its not getting anything if document didnt match

Comment: err is to check if error occurs while quering , it will be null if no error occurs @johndoe

Comment: could you explain how api apply to '/api' , why its written that way api middleware, router https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens :)